# How to Dynamically change Themes of website using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, view, themes, bootswatch

in my website i want to dynamically assign Themes in application.erb.html using  dropdown on  selected change of my ruby on rails application..

my application.html.erb file as follows

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "#{current_theme}" %> 
<%= select_tag(:current_theme, options_for_select([['Cerulean'], ['superhero'], 'Amelia'], ['Cosmo']])) %>
```

i want change my current theme dynamically 
my requirement is want to assign theme on dropdown select change

please help me

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create separate directories for each theme so they can be managed in convenient way. Next you select a default theme and store it in the browser session. When user changes the theme you need to trigger change event on dropdown, update the session and select the theme. So in your `layouts/application.html.haml` you will do something like this.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "#{session[:theme]}" %> 
<%= select_tag(:current_theme, options_for_select([['Cerulean'], ['superhero'], 'Amelia'], ['Cosmo']])) %>
```